# Supported AudioEffects

Tags: android, audio, opensl, audioeffect

I'm trying to determine which OpenSL ES effects are supported by the running device.

the AudioEffect class of the Andorid SDK provide a [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html#queryEffects%28%29) to do so.

> `public static Descriptor[] queryEffects ()`

my problem is that given all the [AudioEffect.Descriptor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.Descriptor.html) returned by that method i don't know how to determine if one of them is actually the one i require.

> **public UUID type**
>
> Added in API level 9 Indicates the generic type of the effect
>   (Equalizer, Bass boost ...). The UUID corresponds to the OpenSL ES
>   Interface ID for this type of effect.

the *[type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.Descriptor.html#type)* attribute seems to be the one I should use but I can't find an OpenSL ES reference where all the effect type UUIDs are specified.

Do you know where i can find one?

I could find out the UUIDs testing the [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html#queryEffects%28%29) result on a device but,

can I assume that the UUID is always the same on every device for a particular type of effect?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [libOpenSLES.so.variables.txt](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/ndk/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/symbols/libOpenSLES.so.variables.txt) for a list of effect name definitions.
If you want to find where the ID actually is defined you should look in the [corresponding header file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/media/+/android-4.1.1_r6.1/audio_effects/include/audio_effects). For `SL_IID_PRESETREVERB` you should look in `effect_presetreverb.h`, and so on.

Comment: thanks man, the UUID defined in the header file you pointed out is the same i found testing on my device. Now, can i assume that it's always the same on every android device on earth?

Comment: It seems unlikely that the definition of those IIDs would change, since that would break existing apps that are using those IIDs. You really ought to use the `SL_IID_` defines rather than hardcoding the same values though.